# How can I place images from Excel into Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, hyperlink, jpeg, mail-merge

I have 10 links to images in an Excel file, and I have 10 pages in a Microsoft Word document. I'd like the Microsoft Word document to import each image from the `.xls` file and place it in a designated spot in the `.doc` file.

Any advice on how to do this? I know perl/python scripts can, but I'd like to know if a more user-friendly option exists in Microsoft Office. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide example files?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this VB macro code in Excel to copy 29 charts from one Excel sheet to a Word document.

If you have images rather than charts, you'll need to change the lines:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
```

to something that selects and copies the data type you have.

```
Sub copycharts()

Dim word As Object
Dim doc As Object
On Error Resume Next

Set word = GetObject(, "word.application") 'gives error 429 if Word is not open
If Err = 429 Then
   Set word = CreateObject("word.application") 'creates a Word application
   Err.Clear
End If

With word
   .Visible = True
   .Documents.Add
End With

Sheets("charts").Select
i = 29
Do While i > 0
   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Activate
   ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
   With word.Selection
    'Paste Chart
   .Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=14, Placement:=wdInLine, _
       DisplayAsIcon:=False
   End With
i = i - 1
Loop
End Sub
```